# Determine matrix repræsentation of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $L:P_2($$\mathbb R$$)$ → $P_2($$\mathbb R$$)$ be a linear operator given by:
$L(α + βX)$ = $(3α + 2β) + (α + 2β)X$ for some $α,β$ in  $\mathbb R$
I want to find the matrix repræsentation of the linear operator. A basis of $P_2($$\mathbb R$$)$ could be $(1,X,X^2)$ but how do I find the matrix repræsentation?
I Intuitively I want to find $P(1)$, $P(X)$, $P(X^2)$ and then, by the coefficients find the matrix repræsentation. But what would the above be? Any tips would be appreaciated.

Comment: You have to find $L(1),\ L(X),\ L(X^2)$, But what do mean by $P_2(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: Yes of couse, I misswrote. But what would that be exactly. $L(1)=3+1$?

Comment: With your current definition, it is not clear what $L(X^2)$ should be. I assume that you are referring instead to an operator $L:P_1(\Bbb R) \to P_1(\Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we want the representation of $L:P_1(\Bbb R) \to P_1(\Bbb R)$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B = (1,X)$. We obtain the $i$th column of the matrix by computing the image of the $i$th basis element. For instance, in order to compute the second column, we compute
$$
L(X) = L(0 + 1 \cdot X) = (3\cdot 0 + 2 \cdot 1) + (0 + 2 \cdot 1)X = 2 + 2X.
$$
The coordinate vector of $L(X)$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is $(2,2)$, so this is the second column of the matrix. That is, we have
$$
[L]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{? & 2\\? & 2}.
$$
By following the same process, we should find the first column of the matrix to be $(3,1)$.